# The ambient light sensor/camera/accelerometer isn't working on the Nexus 7. Are there plans to support it?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

There are several sensors and devices on the Nexus 7 that are not currently working with Ubuntu that work in Android.  Are there plans to support these sensors/devices?

Answer (score 1):

There are plans to support all of the modules and sensors found in the Nexus 7.  This is one area in specific where help from the community would be an enormous help.  The status of this ongoing goal can be found in the meeting notes from a UDS Session about enabling all of the sensors, and can be found here: http://summit.ubuntu.com/uds-r/meeting/21334/desktop-r-arm-input-sensor-drivers/